# ChartJS bar not showing up for simple data points

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js

Here's a simple chart.js horizontal bar chart I'm using:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx,{
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [
        "Foo",
        "Bar",
        "Baz"
    ],
    datasets: [
    {
        data: [725000, 600000, 900000],
        backgroundColor: [
          "#ccf6ec",
          "#ff6654",
          "#009784"
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
          "#ccf6ec",
          "#ff6654",
          "#009784"
        ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

---

If I change the values to be closer to each other I see the three bars. I need it to draw the bars so they are always visible, even if the values are widely different.

Is there a configuration I missed? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason, chart.js uses the smallest amount in data as minimum ticks value. Simply adding `ticks.min: 0` apparently solves the issue:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart')
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Foo",
      "Bar",
      "Baz"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [725000, 600000, 900000],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#ccf6ec",
        "#ff6654",
        "#009784"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#ccf6ec",
        "#ff6654",
        "#009784"
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          min: 0
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```